# combine logical expression for StaticMemeoryTranslatorPlugin used in VexRiscv

Tags: scala, spinalhdl

I want to use 2 static memory regions for a vexriscv soc using SpinalHdl.

Having very little experience with **SpinalHdl** and **Scala**, so maybe I miss a small detail.

- I tried this to instantiate 2 StaticMemoryTranslatorPlugins :

  ```
        plugins ++= List(
        new StaticMemoryTranslatorPlugin(
          ioRange      = _.msb 
        ),
        new StaticMemoryTranslatorPlugin(
          ioRange      = _(31 downto 16) === 0x0001
        ))
  ```

This gives an exception during cpu-generation.

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: ??? vexriscv.MemoryTranslator
[error]     at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[error]     at spinal.core.package$.assert(core.scala:467) .....
```

- Another way I tried is to combine the logical expression, as this :

  ```
          new StaticMemoryTranslatorPlugin(
              ioRange      = ( _.msb )  || ( _(31 downto 16) === 0x0001 )
            )
  ```

This gives me a scale error about expanding the fuction :

```
[error] /home/svhb/dev/JifHybrid/cpu/VexRiscv/src/main/scala/vexriscv/demo/VexRiscv_vdw_1.scala:125:36: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.msb)
[error]                   ioRange      = ( _.msb )  || ( _(31 downto 16) === 0x0001 )
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like I thought, it's my lack of knowledge on the scala syntax itself.

I must fully specify the function to do some extra logic expressions on the iorange function!

```
new StaticMemoryTranslatorPlugin(
     ioRange      = a => (a.msb) || (a(31 downto 16) === 0x0001)
  )
```

instead of just using : ioRange      = ( _.msb )  || ( _(31 downto 16) === 0x0001 )

Have a nice day;)